# Flot: Adjusting y-axis scale on a multiple Y-axes chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, flot, multiple-axes

I am creating a multiple Y axes chart in flot with autorange option.
My issue is that sometimes after the graph is plotted, i need to adjust the scale of some Y axis, and i'd like to do this by clicking the selected axis and scrolling the mouse or something similar to adjust the scale. I've been looking for this option in FLOT API, in google and here, but still haven't found something similar. I've been thinking of selecting the Y axis following this example (http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-interacting/index.html) and then open a pop-up window with a form inside to write the min. and max. value for the axis, and then plot the graph again, but i think it could be better doing the way i described. Do you have any ideas? Can someone help me to find some way to do it?

Comment: If you want to change the axes, you have to redraw. There is no way around this.

Comment: The `navigation plugin` already does what you describe: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/navigate/index.html.  Scrolling the mouse wheel zooms in and out.  I actually prefer your pop-up idea, it gives the user more finite control.

Comment: Thanks Mark, yes that plugins does it but only in one axis and i need to do it in a multiple axes graph, and i don't know how to do it...

Comment: Can you give us an idea of why you're scaling one y-axis but not another?  That would imply that the value of the data changes as you zoom, which is not what most people would expect.

Comment: Hi DNS, thanks for your comment and sorry for taking so long to answer you... What I really need is to adjust the min and max value of each y-axis individually in the chart, in order to the graph be easier to understand... But i'd like to adjust those ranges with the mouse wheel after selecting one y-scale... Thanks